# Are badges' thresholds subject to change?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Currently, there are [~1362564](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609102) users who have the ["Vote Up" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Since the beginning of this year, [1554407](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609110) users have joined Stack Overflow, and [86837](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609109) of them have > 15 reputation points, meaning that they have the vote up privilege.

[Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) are awarded at a fixed reputation threshold, for example, the ["Nice Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) is awarded when your answer gets ≥ 10 votes.

**My question**

Since the community is growing, and since badges can sometimes reflect someone's strength/knowledge in some field, will thresholds of "awarded at" be changed someday? Does someone take statistics into consideration? Or, if the thresholds are unrelated to number of users, on what were they set/based?

Note that I'm *not requesting* changes, I'm just wondering...

Comment: It is not without precedent that privilege levels might increase. New SE sites start out with lower thresholds for privileges and increase them over time as the site grows. However, badge thresholds don't change, and badges are almost never revoked.

Comment: @CodyGray Do you think they should be a connection between #users and badges' threshold?

Comment: It's an interesting question for sure. I hadn't thought of this before. I'm leaning towards no, but would have to think on it before making a final decision.

Comment: Usually you have not only more users but also more technologies people are discussing. Have you checked the number of tags? Many users stay in their niche, which might actually grow or shrink.

Comment: Why would the number of users change the threshold at which we consider an individual user to be sufficiently knowledgeable to wield the upvote (or gain any other privilege)? Is it because you expect that the individual users will be receiving more upvotes themselves from the mass of users?

Comment: Similar question from a long time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1587/130126

Comment: @beaker Yes. If more and more users have the privilege of upvoting, many (good) answers will get more upvotes.

Comment: If that's the case, then the average score for an upvoted answer after some arbitrary time period (a month? a year?) should be increasing as the number of users increases. I have no idea how difficult it would be to get that data.

Comment: If they did this for badges or privileges, it would be pretty terrible for people who only look at niche tags. It's already pretty difficult to get the tag badges for niche tags. Reputation is much harder to come by, as are certain non-tag badges (like Nice Answer).

Answer (score 26):

I don't think so (but of course Stack Overflow may make other decisions in the future), but they might introduce new badges.

They have done so for the [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1276/proofreader) badge, a bronze badge for reviewing 100 suggested edits, which was created at a time where that was the only review queue. As @approxiblue points out, there was a Reviewer badge as well, more or less corresponding to the current Steward badge. After the other ones (First Posts, Close Votes, etc.) were instantiated, a new three-tier badge set was developed: [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian) (1) - [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) (250) - [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) (1000). These did not replace the existing badge for suggested edits.

Also, even though there are more users capable of upvoting now, there are also more users who can write a Nice Answer on the same question as you. So, to put it in economic terms, the market has become bigger, but the competition as well.

Comment: Right, we could award Platinum badges, or perhaps Rhodium and Palladium.

Comment: Don't forget Unicornium.

Comment: Unobtainium would make for a fun badge.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) is made of unobtainium (at least on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that Jon Skeet has several of those, but there is no entity available in HTML to display them.

Comment: The [Reviewer badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) used to have a higher threshold than it is currently, interestingly.

Answer (score 15):

IMO, instead of increasing the threshold values for the existing badges, rolling out new badges with increased cutoffs will be easier as well as motivating for the existing users.